# Script on demand stopped working after moving code from html to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-events

I've stumbled upon quite weird problem.

I made my website using ajax (jQuery load to be exact) content in html it all worked fine, but I had to rewrite it to PHP mainly because of SEO problems with Google dynamic `#` - links. Any way now the script on demand executed with scripts below in such order how's it shown doesn't work. BUT apparently the code is quite fine, or seems to be in some cases because it works when `#!` link is loaded and main script calls the required script on demand used for this certain link, even if I call them all at once in main script file they do work! Example of this phenomenon:

```
function getalljs() {
    getJs("js/vertical.js","js");
    getJs("js/steps.js","js");
    getJs("js/animatesteps.js","js");
    }
```

There's another weird thing going on there, one of the on demand scripts loaded the same way as written below, does actually load but jQuery load does not (it contains background animation).

Those are my scripts:

This function is used to fadeout content, load new one, change url hash and fadein:

```
function loadajax(toLoad, rest, div, js) {
    window.location.hash = toLoad;
    div.fadeOut(150, loadContent);

    function loadContent() {
        contentload(toLoad, rest, div, js);
        reappear();
    }

    function reappear() {
        div.fadeIn(1000);
    }

    return false;

}
```

As you probably noticed it calls another function, this one is used to load the html, with jQuery load.

```
function contentload(fragment, rest, div, js) {
    fragment = fragment.slice(1).replace('!', '')
    div.load((fragment + rest), getJs(js, "js"));
}
```

And yes this one calls yet another to grab Javascript used on newly loaded content:

```
function getJs(filename, filetype){
 if (filetype=="js"){ //if filename is a external JavaScript file
  var fileref=document.createElement('script')
  fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
  fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
 }
 else if (filetype=="css"){ //if filename is an external CSS file
  var fileref=document.createElement("link")
  fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
  fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
  fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
 }
 if (typeof fileref!="undefined")
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
}
```

here goes the code responsible to calling this into motion:

```
$("#horizontal_cssmenu a").click(function () {
        var div = $('#contentsth');

        var toLoad = $(this).attr('href');
        var rest = '?ajax=1';
        var javka = 'js/vertical.js';
        loadajax(toLoad, rest, div, javka);

        return false;
    });
```

Comment: There is no PHP in your code, so it's not related. Do you see any errors inside console? Does browser tries to load correct URL, did you tried to debug where it start "to not work"?